# What module controls Commerce Kickstart 2 add to cart popup?

Tags: commerce

I have installed the demo store Commerce Kickstart 2. Going through and changing things here and there somehow I've affected the popup functionality. It no longer fires when adding something to your cart. I'm thinking I may have just turned off the module that controls this? Or maybe it's a setting I clicked off?

Comment: Do you install ajax commerce? Did you also  check in admin/commerce/config/checkout or maybe any rule you create it might be in conflict with the cart process.

Comment: 1) I have only installed the basic distribution and no additional modules but it's supposed to working as it is on my dev version. 2) I don't see anything particular regarding the popup in the checkout settings. I could be just missing it. 3) I've added no new rules at all.

Comment: what about the views that control the cart? maybe accidently disable something there? When I started working with commerce this helped me http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/modifying-shopping-cart-using-views

Comment: Nope...embarrassing to say but I was tired of seeing the messages and so I commented them out of the tpl not realizing this section also renders the popup. I knew I had just turned this off somehow...once I started firebugging the demo I saw it was in messages and started vaguely remembering that I had done that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Commerce Kickstart 7.x-2.0-rc3 and up, the module is [Commerce add to cart confirmation](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_confirmation)
(Previously this functionality was a part of the base product feature and couldn't be disabled).

Comment: Technically the correct answer.